# Rails - find or create - is there a find or build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using:

```
XXX.find_or_create_by_uuid(XXXX)
```

Is there a way to do find or build?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try `XXX.find_or_initialize_by_uuid(XXXX)`

Comment: Note: You cannot use a bang `!` operator with `find_or_initialize_by` like you can with `find_or_create_by`. This is because the bang is used to raise an exception if there is trouble saving the object, which doesn't apply when just initializing.

Answer (score 32):

Since Rails 4 this is `XXX.find_or_initialize_by(uuid: XXXX)`

Answer (score -3):

In case you want to make your own (Rails 5):

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.find_or_build_by hash
    result = all.where(hash)
    result.present? ? result : none.build(hash)
  end
end
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Other developers that are used to the standard `find_or_initialize_by` will be confused, and worse, judgemental towards you for doing this.