# ActiveRecord find_or_build_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to perform:

```
    XXX.find_or_build_by_language_id(attributes)
```

I found

```
    XXX.find_or_initialize_by_language_id(attributes)
```

but that only set language_id and no other attributes. Even if I manually sets the attributes, the record is not saved when I perform XXX.save.

I just read [Rails - find or create - is there a find or build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844458), which seems related to my problem but does not fit my needs.

### Edit

Let's use this scenario

```
# db/migrations/create_models.rb
class CreateModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :employees do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :city
      t.references :company
    end
  end
end
```

-

```
# app/models/employee.rb
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

-

```
# app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end
```

-

```
# rails console
:001> c = Company.new
 => #<Company id: nil, name: nil> 
:002> c.employees
 => []
:003> e = c.employees.find_or_initialize_by_name(:name => 'foo', :city => 'bar')
 => #<Employee id: nil, name: "foo", city: "bar", company_id: nil>
:004> c.employees
 => []
:005> c.save
 => true
:006> c.employees
 => []
:007> e.save
 => true
:008> c = Company.first
 => #<Company id: 1, name: nil>
:009> c.employees
 => [#<Employee id: 1, name: "foo", city: "bar", company_id: 1>]
:010> e = c.employees.find_or_initialize_by_name(:name => 'foo', :city => 'baz')
 => #<Employee id: 1, name: "foo", city: "bar", company_id: 1> 
:011> e.city = 'baz'
 => "baz"
:012> c.employees
 => [#<Employee id: 1, name: "foo", city: "bar", company_id: 1>] 
:013 > c.save
 => true 
:014> c.employees
 => [#<Employee id: 1, name: "foo", city: "bar", company_id: 1>]
```

### Problems

1. :004 => The Employee from :003 is not added to c.employees
2. :006 => The Employee from :003 is saved with c
3. :010 => The city attribute of employee is not set
4. :014 => THe city attribute of employee is not updated when saving company

Comment: What about find_or_initalize_by doesn't fit your needs? If .save isn't working, make sure all your validations are being met.

Comment: Check if the attributes are `attr_accessible`(or not `attr_protected`) and check the return value of `save` to see if your validations pass.

Comment: I've included a complete example to better expose the problem.

Comment: Your example seems to work correctly. Try `c.reload` between 004, 005 & 006 and the new employee should appear. Furthermore in 010 you have already an employee with name "foo", therefore it will be found rather than initialized with your parameters.  In 014 you should probably try reloading the employees again as well.

Comment: The exemple works according the doc but does not suit my needs. Reloading does not help, it would have worked with find_or_create though but saving company does not save employees. Also in my use case I need my attributes not to be ignored when the record is retirieved from DB.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this?

```
employee_attrs = {:name => 'foo', :city => 'bar'}
e = c.employees.where(employee_attrs).first || c.employees.build(employee_attrs)
```

Comment: You can just create your own method `find_or_initialize` based on this solution.

Comment: I'll accept that answer because it is propably the expected behavior for a ```find_or_build``` method, but the default find implementation is not working for me. I need the record retrieved to be set with new values (see. problem 3).

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here is the implementation I came with. It can probably be simpler, but it suits my needs:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class AssociationCollection < AssociationProxy
      alias_method :old_method_missing, :method_missing

      def method_missing(method_id, *arguments, &block)
        if /^find_or_build_by_([_a-zA-Z]\w*)$/ =~ method_id.to_s
          names = $1.split('_and_')
          find_or_build_by(names, *arguments)
        else
          old_method_missing(method_id, *arguments, &block)
        end
      end

      def find_or_build_by(names, *arguments)
        values = arguments[0]

        throw InvalidArgument unless values.keys.first.kind_of?(String)

        record = Array.new(self).find do |r|
          names.inject(true) do |memo, name|
            memo && (values[name].to_s == r.send(name).to_s)
          end
        end

        if record
          sanitized_values = record.send(:sanitize_for_mass_assignment, values)
          sanitized_values.each {|k, v| record.send("#{k}=", v)}
        else
          record = build(values)
        end

        return record
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you use an initializer file to handle the update to ActiveRecord?

Comment: Disclaimer: This answer is quite old and I don't use it anymore. I guess I used some sort of initializer or maybe I just included the file in my environment.rb but I don't remember exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code for my Rails 4.2.x app.

```
#config/initializers/collection_proxy.rb
ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.class_eval do
  alias_method :old_method_missing, :method_missing

  def method_missing(method_id, *arguments, &block)
    if /^find_or_build_by([_a-zA-Z]\w*)$/ =~ method_id.to_s
      names = $1.split('_and_')
      find_or_build_by(names, *arguments)
    else
      old_method_missing(method_id, *arguments, &block)
    end
  end

  def find_or_build_by(names, *arguments)
    where(names).first || build(names)
  end
end
```

You can use it like this.

```
XXX.find_or_build_by(attributes)
```