# Rails: find_or_create_by equivalent that will not persist until save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using this code block to retrieve a user or create a new one:

```
user = User.find_or_create_by!(email:params[:email])
```

However, I don't necessarily want to persist the new user to the database.

Is there something like "find_or_new_by" that will only persist upon:

```
user.save
```

Comment: Not sure if anything new has happened but this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833663/activerecord-find-or-build-by) might explain better. If you can find a better solution, that might be worth amending.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`#find_or_initialize_by`](http://devdocs.io/rails/activerecord/relation#method-i-find_or_initialize_by). Instead of calling `create`, the named method calls `new`. To save the object (assuming it is initialized, and not found), you will call `save` as you want.

And if you look at the source code for the method, it does *exactly* what you are looking for!

```
def find_or_initialize_by(attributes, &block)
  find_by(attributes) || new(attributes, &block)
end
```

On the docs page I provided with the method link, I was not able to find a bang (`!`) version of the method. Using the bang will raise an error. Depending on your use, you may not need it at all.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first_or_initialize
```

it will just initialize it if does not exists.